# Prawn Tables: Block is not executing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I've run into a really strange issue with my rails/prawn code.

I'm generating a table and *trying* to change the font style of the first row with the following code:

```
pdf.table(data) do
    rows.first.style(:font_style => :bold)
end
```

The table is generated, but nothing inside the block is executed. I've tried putting a debugger statement in the block, but it doesn't even hit that. As per suggestions found by Googling, I've tried adding a block argument, eg:

```
pdf.table(data) do |t|
    t.rows.first.style(:font_style => :bold)
end
```

along with several other variations, but to no avail. I've tried various configurations by changing config/environments.rb, but that didn't work either. Specifically, my questions is, why isn't the code inside the block executing?

I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone might have.

Comment: If it helps, I'm using prawn(0.8.4), prawn-core(0.8.4), and prawn-layout(0.8.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had similar issues with tables in prawn. I think the syntax had changed from a lot of the guides around out there, but I can't really remember - it was a while back! This is how we went about styling a row in the end:

```
pdf.table(data) do
  style row(0), :style => :bold
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! However, I tried this, but I got the same results as before. Good suggestion, though. I didn't know about that syntax.

Comment: You may want to give 0.11.1.pre a try. That's what we went for in the end (and what the above example is from). We had similar issues with some things just not working as expected. Haven't run into any problems in the few months the code has been in production..

Comment: Great! Worked like a charm once I installed 0.11.1 pre (with gem install prawn --pre). Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

both

```
style(row(0)) {|x| x.font_style = :bold}
```

and

```
style row(0), :font_style => :bold
```

works for me. Your

```
style => :bold
```

does not work. Btw: prawn (0.12.0) here.